# How do I manage to embed a video player in rotate banner module in DRUPAL7

Tags: jquery, drupal

As the title states,I am trying to implement and modify rotate banner module such that it rotates and has image as background and a video player attached just like youtube ad for one banner slide in drupal 7.

The only solution I have come up with is enable textarea to interpret PHP or HTML like Body.

I have been stuck for the whole day.Could anyone give me some hint...

I tried ddblock module,turns out that this is not working well on drupal 7 and the author just abandoned the project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Views + Views Slideshow + Embedded Media Field + Media: YouTube modules.

You can create a Content Type with the Embedded Youtube Media field attached to it, create a View with that field filtering by your new content type and use the Views Slideshow module to display your view wherever you want.

- Views: http://drupal.org/project/views
- Views Slideshow: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow
- Embedded Media Field: http://drupal.org/project/emfield
- Media: Youtube: http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube